# How to copy data from multiple folder for deploy through aws code pipeline with buildspec.yml?

Tags: amazon-s3, build, aws-codepipeline, artifact

i am setting up code pipeline for ci/cd and have folder structure like below during build.

Foder1/files
Folder2/subfolder/files

Now i want to deploy it to s3 as below

Folder2/subfolder/files to the root of the s3.
Foder1/files as it to the root of the s3

so s3 will have

Folder1/files
files --- from subfolder

I want to do it with artifact. my current setting in buildspec is

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
    - 'mobileStaticPages/**/*'
  base-directory: 'rentscribe/dist*'
```

but folder1 files are not coping as it is not in base directory

Answer (score 0):

In your Buildspec, first have a staging folder prepared with the files to deploy, the use that staging folder as artifact's base-dir:

```
  post_build:
    commands:
      - mkdir staging
      - cp -r Folder2/subfolder/files staging
      - cp -r Foder1/files staging

  artifacts:
    files:
      - '**/*'
    base-directory: staging
```

Comment: I fixed this by adding secondary artifact in code deploy and code build..